# Disable Windows web-results in start

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-search

When you press the windows key, type Chrome, but spell it wrong, IT OPENS EDGE! I had an option configured, that Cortana was completely disabled and I wouldn't get web-results either, after updating to Windows 10 Home 1803 (17134.228), I get the web results again, I've played around in the registry, and the group policy editor, but still, I get these web-results.

I tried this trick I found at https://www.neowin.net/news/the-windows-10-spring-update-no-longer-lets-you-disable-web-search-in-start/,
It said to run this registry file:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
„BingSearchEnabled“=dword:00000000
„AllowSearchToUseLocation“=dword:00000000
„CortanaConsent“=dword:00000000
```

But as mentioned, this was useless. not even after a restart.

Comment: I have confirmed those registry keys actually do work in the current 1803 build.

Comment: @Ramhound These do not seem to work for me. Did you use any methods that may have been different from from the instructions on the website?

Comment: Confirmed working in 1809 build too. Regedit > Address: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search` right click right pane >? add new DWORD value then use the text as described as the key names.

Comment: @AndyGee I just spent all day yesterday upgrading to 1809 and it works now, I haven't touched anything, it just works. Thanks for all your help